# Can the forecasts using exponential smoothing be negative in value?

Tags: forecasting

Hello
I am trying to forecast using different exponential smoothing methods(Linear and Winter's). For the optimal parameters, I am getting negative values of the forecasats. 
I am assuming it means that the values will be zero, since it is a sales forecast. 
I wanted to know if negative values denote something wrong with the model or is it possible to have negative values in forecast. Since it is just a model, I think we can get negative values for certain type of time series.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92443/27433

Comment: Also related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/107467/27433

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Holt's or Winter-Holt's exponential smoothing methods can give negative values for purely non-negative input values because of the *trend factor* which acts as a kind of inertia, which can drive the time series below zero. Normal exponential smoothing doesn't have this problem, it's always smoothing *inwards*, it never overshoots.

Comment: However, the prediction intervals can get negative. How can one prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get negative values for certain kinds of models.  You might want to explore more complicated models than simple exponential smoothing.