# Getting Negative Forecasting Values

Tags: r, forecasting

My data set in R contains the values like

```
a   b  c
15  30  15
10  40  19
19  10  41
40  25  27
```

I have used the formula `forecast(sample$a,h=5)` after invoking `require(forecast)`. Got the negative forecasting values.

```
Point Forecast       Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
5       39.99787    1.036967  78.95877  -19.58769  99.58343
6       39.99787  -22.550980 102.54672  -55.66234 135.65808
7       39.99787  -47.693434 127.68917  -94.11441 174.11015
8       39.99787  -76.830999 156.82674 -138.67647 218.67221
9       39.99787 -111.825136 191.82088 -192.19538 272.19112
```

To avoid this I have used log values for forecasting and as a result I got the new values like

```
forecast(log(sample$a),h=5)

  Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
5       3.688805 3.007466 4.370144 2.646787 4.730823
6       3.688805 2.725294 4.652316 2.215243 5.162367
7       3.688805 2.508770 4.868840 1.884097 5.493513
8       3.688805 2.326229 5.051381 1.604926 5.772684
9       3.688805 2.165407 5.212203 1.358969 6.018641
```

If I look at the forecasted values before and after the log transformation, lot of difference is there. Can someone assist me which one is appropriate between these to forecasting values? Which values should I consider as a forecasted values for the variable 'a'?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. With first forecast you got positive values (39.99787) with a broad forecast interval due to the very small sample size. With forecasting values on log scale you got forecasts on log scale (3.688805) that transformed give you similar results (exp(3.688805) = 39.99702). Where is the problem?

Comment: from the forecast point 6 on wards, got the negative values like 6       39.99787  -22.550980 102.54672  -55.66234 135.65808
7       39.99787  -47.693434 127.68917  -94.11441 174.11015
8       39.99787  -76.830999 156.82674 -138.67647 218.67221
9       39.99787 -111.825136 191.82088 -192.19538 272.19112

Comment: Related: [Can a mathematically sound prediction interval have a negative lower bound?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92443/1352)

Comment: As @Tim points out, your point forecasts are positive, but your *prediction intervals* go negative. I'd recommend that you look at [the question I linked to above](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92443/1352).